# load() method not working with Random Forest model in R

Tags: r, analytics

I am creating a random forest model and saving it to disk from one instance of RGui:

```
rf_model<-randomForest(y~x,ntree=500)
save(rf_model,file='D:/RandomForestModel.rda')
```

the contents of `rf_model` are as follows:

```
> rf_model

Call:
 randomForest(formula = y ~ x, ntree = 500) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 1

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.392876
                    % Var explained: 0.34
```

Now when I try to load the same model from an another instance of RGui then I get following contents:

```
> load('D:/RandomForestModel.rda')
> rf_model

....
....
 0.2199068  0.2199068  0.2199068  1.0000000  0.2199068  0.2199068   0.2199068 
      8156       8157       8158 
 0.2199068  0.2199068  0.2199068 

$test
NULL

$inbag
NULL

$terms
y ~ x
attr(,"variables")
list(y, x)
attr(,"factors")
  x
y 0
x 1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "x"
attr(,"order")
[1] 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 0
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"predvars")
list(y, x)
attr(,"dataClasses")
        y         x 
"numeric" "numeric" 

attr(,"class")
[1] "randomForest.formula" "randomForest"
```

Here is the problem i am facing, the format of the saved model and loaded model are different thus i can't use this loaded model for further analysis.

I also tried saving and loading other models like linear model and ARIMA model, all these models are loading perfectly fine. However Random Forest model completely changes the contents and thus is not usable for forecasting/prediction.

Comment: You have to load the randomForest _package_ with `library(randomForest)` to be able to use your saved model object.

Comment: It worked :) thanks for your response.